# Find the exact word position in string

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string.

```
$string = red,green,blue,yellow,black;
```

Now I have a variable which is the position of the word I am searching for.

```
$key = 2;
```

I want to get the word with the position of 2. In this case, the answer would be `blue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://codepad.org/LA35KzEZ

```
$a = explode( ',', $string );
echo $a[ $key ];
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to solve this, would be by converting the string into an array using explode().

```
$string = ...;
$string_arr = explode(",", $string);
//Then to find the string in 2nd position

echo $string_arr[1]; //This is given by n-1 when n is the position you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = preg_split( '/[\s,]+/', $str );

echo $string[$key];
```

This works by splitting a sentence into words based on word boundaries (Spaces, commas, periods, etc). It's more flexible than `explode()`, unless you are only working with comma delimited strings.

For example, if `str` = 'Hello, my name is dog. How are you?', and `$key` = 5, You would get 'How'.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$string = 'red,green,blue,yellow,black';
$key = 2;
```

Then (< PHP 5.4):

```
$string_array = explode(',', $string);
$word = $string_array[$key];
```

Then (>= PHP 5.4):

```
$word = explode(',', $string)[$key];
```

Comment: Note: array dereferencing (i.e., `explode(...)[$key]`) will only work in PHP 5.4 or greater. Prior to 5.4, it would need to be on two lines (i.e., `$words = explode(...); $word = $words[$key];`

Comment: @Wiseguy Thats why I changed it. I have been in c# land too long.

Comment: Nice; you were changing it as I was writing that comment. It _does_ work as of 5.4.0, so your code wasn't wrong, but many (most?) people are still using older versions.

Comment: @Wiseguy Including me. I had no idea they were implementing it on 5.4.0. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your words will be separated by commas you can do something like:

```
$key = 2;
$string = "red,green,blue,yellow,black";
$arr = explode(",",$string);
echo $arr[$key];
```